# Android: Setting maxSDK version for Android 1.5 app

Tags: android, sdk, version, max, min

I've released an android app with the property

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="4"/>
```

now my app seems to crash on android 1.5 devices (i guess because i use drawable-mdpi/hdpi,...)

so thought it would be good to release the same app just for 1.5 devices (not using the mdpi/hdpi-directories). but when i use

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" 
      android:targetSdkVersion="3"
      android:maxSdkVersion="3" />
```

it doesn't compile for 1.5 (it states that target and maxsdkversion are unknown properties). 
(if i set the jar-sdk to 1.6 it works fine).

So what is the best way to solve my problem? Is the app runable if I compile with 1.6 sdk but restrict it to sdk 3 (1.5) ? Or would this also crash since the sdk3 doesn't know the manifest-attributes "target/maxSdkVersion"?

Any other ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Don't give up on a single cross-compatible APK just yet. Are you sure your app is crashing because of the mdpi/hdpi folders? Setting the min/target like that is enough to make a compatible APK, even with the split-out folder, so I'm guessing the crash is related to something else. What's the traceback?

Comment: don't have any traceback. just comments from the users. and i just added a new http-fetch method, and new icons (hdpi,mdpi+adjusted manifest). works fine on other devices (mine included) so i think this has to be the issue

Answer (score -1):

you need a drawable-v3 entry in res folder  for android 1.5..

your minSdk will read 3 targetSDKVersion will read 4

That should get rid of all crashes..