# Android application version

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest

My application is working under Android 2.2 version and when I installed that application apk file in Android tablet using version 3.0,it is not working..so what should i done with my code so that my application should work universally?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Any error messages?  LogCat would be useful.

Comment: This link would help you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745168/android-setting-maxsdk-version-for-android-1-5-app

Answer (score 1):

You have to write this statement into manifest.xml file

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
```

Comment: @Kanika i edited the answer, so that the statement is now shown

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the android:minSdkVersion in Androidmanifest.xml to the 11 so that it will work in 3.0 as well

Comment: but i want to use it universally from android 2.2 phone set to android 3.2 tablets..so if I will write android:minSdkVersion :11,then is it possible that this appcation can also work on phone set 2.2?

Comment: it will work in both the versions if it is android 3.2 then android:minSdkVersion = 13